# WPF: Image stretched when placed in StackPanel in button

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, stretch

I'm making a sort-of toolbar in WPF (StackPanel containing Buttons containing StackPanels containing Images and TextBlock...)
Here is the code for one button :

```
<Button x:Name="btnGraph" FontWeight="Normal" Background="{DynamicResource accentColor}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource accentColor}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Resources/diagnostic_chart1.png" Stretch="None"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Graph"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

As you can see, the image in the button is stretched, but the **same** image code outside the button (in the container StackPanel), it works correctly : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OymzT.png)

I've tried a lot of things, but nothing worked.
Is there a way to make it works ?

EDIT: I also tried changing the DPI of images from 72 to 96, no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image doesn't look stretched to me; the size seems right.  It actually looks like it's rendering across pixel boundaries, giving it a blurred appearance. Try setting `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on your root visual.